# Cosa vuol dire "biolca" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel racconto *Il signor Podestà*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Maurizio però insisteva nella delazione. Quei due continuavano a vedersi, a fare, nottetempo, nel suo campo di fagioli. Ecco un particolare tormentoso. Il podestà aveva troppo buon ricordo dei fagioleti: era cosí comodo e gustoso, ricordava, assestare la ragazza in modo che le sue natiche campeggiassero sul dorso della **biolca**… Che Matilde uscisse con Alfredo (facendola da furbi) non era poi estremamente grave, ciò che lo scottava era sapere che se la godesse a quel modo nel suo campo di fagioli.

Qualcuno di voi saprebbe spiegare il significato di "biolca" in questo passaggio? La definizione di questo termine come antica unità di misura di superficie che ho trovato nei dizionari non sembra avere molto senso in questo contesto.

Comment: È vero, la biolca è un'unità di misura di superficie; che in questo contesto indichi forse il terreno vero e proprio? Cioè il luogo in cui si consumava il rapporto con la ragazza? 
Ho  trovato qui https://books.google.it/books?id=bzBHAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=biolcA+ORIGINI&source=bl&ots=ctvKLjrizR&sig=ce_O-I7_-Z1NO9HhRIWjwXSeBH8&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjChpvmoM7dAhUKBcAKHZCBCSc4ChDoATADegQIBxAB#v=onepage&q=biolcA%20ORIGINI&f=false che il termine deriva da "bifolca" ovvero è la superficie di terreno che è possibile coprire con una giornata di lavoro di una coppia di buoi

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Questo si spiega anche nel [dizionario De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/biolca).

Comment: Mah. Se c'è un dorso, dato il contesto, viene da pensare che biolca sia una mucca o una particolare sella. Boh

Comment: @CarloAlterego: Quindi, il significato potrebbe essere quello di "[bue](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/biolco)"?

Comment: @charo - non so, ma la risposta accettata non mi convince

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In questo caso, vista la (quasi) contemporaneità dell'autore e lo stile di scrittura, è più che probabile che il termine "biolca", originariamente indicante un'unità di superficie, ed in particolare la superficie di un campo (vedi [De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/biolca)), sia utilizzato per intendere il campo stesso.

Si tratta infatti di una metonimia, nella quale per mezzo di una relazione di tipo qualitativo si indica il misurato con la misura.

Non sul dorso di una mucca, né di un bue, né di una bifolca, ma sul dorso del campo. Sostiene la tesi della metonimia il fatto che l'uso di "dorso" con riferimento a rilievi o campi sia di natura quasi esclusivamente letteraria.

Comment: Spiegazione interessante